# Discord stuck on "Starting..." whenever I launch

Tags: 20.04

Ive tried killing discord to no effect.

I uninstalled and reinstalled. nothing

Ive rebooted. nada

Anone have any ideas?

If I run via the terminal by just typing "discord" I get this and it opens a blank discord window

Discord 0.0.15
Quitting secondary instance.
(node:11523) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

Comment: It can't be running if you actually uninstalled it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto When I said I uninstall to no effect I meant I uninstalled and reinstalled to see if that would work

Comment: That seldom does in any Linux. Purging and/or deleting the hidden settings folder might. Uninstall/install comes from a certain "Windows mentality". How did you install it?

Answer (score 1):

Same here on Ubuntu 21.04. My discord was installed using the apt package.

```
discord/now 0.0.15 amd64 [installed,local]
```

**Solution**

Uninstalling `discord` package (version 0.0.15) and install it snap (version 0.0.16).

```
sudo apt remove discord
sudo snap install discord
```